# npm doesn't install the versions I need for Angular Bootstrap

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, npm, package.json, angular-bootstrap

This is my package.json.

```
{
"name": "MyProject",
"private": true,
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
"test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "5.0.2",
"@angular/common": "5.0.2",
"@angular/compiler": "5.0.2",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.2",
"@angular/core": "5.0.2",
"@angular/forms": "5.0.2",
"@angular/http": "5.0.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.2",
"@angular/platform-server": "5.0.2",
"@angular/router": "5.0.2",
"@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
"@types/chai": "4.0.1",
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
"@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
"angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
"angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
"aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
"aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
"bootstrap": "4.0.0",
"chai": "4.0.2",
"css": "2.2.1",
"css-loader": "0.28.4",
"es6-shim": "0.35.3",
"event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
"expose-loader": "0.7.3",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
"file-loader": "0.11.2",
"html-loader": "0.4.5",
"isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
"jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
"jquery": "3.2.1",
"json-loader": "0.5.4",
"karma": "1.7.0",
"karma-chai": "0.1.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
"karma-cli": "1.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
"karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
"preboot": "4.5.2",
"raw-loader": "0.5.1",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
"rxjs": "5.4.2",
"style-loader": "0.18.2",
"to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
"typescript": "2.4.1",
"url-loader": "0.5.9",
"webpack": "2.5.1",
"webpack-cli": "^2.0.14",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
"webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
"zone.js": "0.8.12"
},
"dependencies": {
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.1.2"
}
}
```

This was, for the most part, generated by ASP.Net Core 2 template with the "dotnet new angular" command. I only needed to add ng-bootstrap and updated the version to what's recommended (Angular should at least be 5.0.2 and Bootstrap should at least be 4.0.0.)

However, when I do "npm install", I get a lower version.

```
├── @angular/animations@4.2.5
├── @angular/common@4.2.5
├── @angular/compiler@4.2.5
├─┬ @angular/compiler-cli@4.2.5
│ └── minimist@1.2.0
├── @angular/core@4.2.5
├── @angular/forms@4.2.5
├── @angular/http@4.2.5
├── @angular/platform-browser@4.2.5
├── @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.2.5
├── @angular/platform-server@4.2.5
├── @angular/router@4.2.5
├── @angular/tsc-wrapped@4.2.5
...
```

As a result, I'm getting the following error when running my app.

```
NodeInvocationException: Can't resolve all parameters for
NgbModalStack: ([object Object], [object Object], [object Object], ?).
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for NgbModalStack: ([object Object], [object Object], [object Object], ?).
at Error (native)
at syntaxError (/MyProject/ClientApp/dist/vendor.js:37092:34)
at CompileMetadataResolver.module.exports.CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata
(/MyProject/ClientApp/dist/vendor.js:51159:35)
at CompileMetadataResolver.module.exports.CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata
(/MyProject/ClientApp/dist/vendor.js:51027:26)
at CompileMetadataResolver.module.exports.CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata
(/MyProject/ClientApp/dist/vendor.js:51013:21)
at CompileMetadataResolver.module.exports.CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata
(/MyProject/ClientApp/dist/vendor.js:51304:40)
at /MyProject/ClientApp/dist/vendor.js:51233:49
at Array.forEach (native)
at CompileMetadataResolver.module.exports.CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata
(/MyProject/ClientApp/dist/vendor.js:51193:19)
at /MyProject/ClientApp/dist/vendor.js:50768:63
```

I'm positive that the error is caused by the wrong versions, as covered by [this issue](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2212).

Comment: Have you looked at the Angular versions required by the other libraries? My guess is that one or more of them requires a lower version.

Comment: Good point. My npm install output didn't inform me which one caused the downgrade. Is there a way to extract that information instead of going through each one to manually check dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Add the npm install ng-bootstrap with the version you want.

Step 2: Delete package-lock.json and node modules folder.

Step 3: Check whether any other unwanted bootstrap is listed in the package.json file. If so remove it and keep the ng-bootstrap version you want in the file.

Step 4: Re-install npm modules npm i.